# android keystore in Visual studio does not have expiration date or certificate

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-android-player

I am trying to create a keystore in Visual studio for android xamarin app

When i create a new keystore, it gets added, but without an expiration date or a SHA certificate. (Refer the test app below)
[image]

[image]

Previously, when I used to do it, the SHA certificate was included in the keystore.
[image]

Am i missing something? Without the certificate, I am not able to upload the generated apk on Google play.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this article about [Manually Signing the APK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/manually-signing-the-apk) to create a New Keystore.

Creating a new keystore requires the command line tool [keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html) from the Java SDK. The following snippet is an example of how to use keytool:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\keytool.exe" -genkeypair -v -keystore <filename>.keystore -alias <key-name> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Comment: Thank you... But though the certificate was not visible on Visual studio, and i checked it with Cmd prompt   -  *** COMMAND TO EXTRACT SHA CERTIFICATE FROM KEYSTORE ***
keytool.exe -list -v -keystore "C:\test.keystore" -alias Test-storepass Test -keypass Test  .        The certificate was present , and was the same as the uploaded apk.  So, I was able to upload the new apk to Google play